# Error parsing metadata commands (server). Check JSON structure and network connectivity (NAT instance or Proxy)' for uniqueId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

i am trying to deploy AWS spot::Fleet
via cloud formation
and i want the commands in metadata will run after the instance is up.
but got this msg:

> Error parsing metadata commands (server). Check JSON structure and
> network connectivity (NAT instance or Proxy)' for uniqueId:
> ip-10-28-6-6

what is wrong with my JSON template file?

```
"MyServer": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
            "Properties": {
                "SpotFleetRequestConfigData": {
                    "IamFleetRole": "arn:aws:iam::6******2:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role",
                    "SpotPrice": "0.15",
                    "TargetCapacity": "1",
                    "LaunchSpecifications": [{
                        "EbsOptimized": "false",
                        "InstanceType": {
                            "Ref": "myInstanceType"
                        },
                        "ImageId": ".....",
                        "SecurityGroups": [ 
                            ......
                        ],
                        "SubnetId": {
                            "Ref": "mySubnet"
                        },
                        "WeightedCapacity": "1",
                        "UserData": {
                            "Fn::Base64": {
                                "Fn::Join": [
                                    "",
                                    [
....
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
            

                    }]
                }

            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "commands": [
                    {
                      "Fn::Join":[
                         "",
                         [
                            "echo ls -l /var/log > /home/MyFile.txt \n",
                            "chmod 777 /var/log \n"
                         ]
                      ]
                   }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the helpers!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Metadata block has an incorrect structure. The AWS::CloudFormation::Init section should include a config section where you provide commands or other configuration details, and the commands themselves should be organized as key-value pairs, not as an array.

Here's the corrected metadata section of your template:

```
"Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
        "config": {
            "commands": {
                "command1": {
                    "command": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "echo ls -l /var/log > /home/MyFile.txt"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "command2": {
                    "command": "chmod 777 /var/log"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Userdata scripts and metadata commands run under the root by default. So you don't need to provide high-level permissions like '777' to /var/log.

Finally, your instance needs to have AWS SSM Agent installed for the AWS::CloudFormation::Init to work.